# Programmatically Create Folder/ Directory in Windows Phone 8/8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to create a folder for my application, to store my application data inside that folder only?

Comment: could be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create folder, how say Smart Developer use that code:

```
//Import classes to your project
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;

//Name of folders
private static string MyFolder = "MyFolder";

//Folders
private StorageFolder Folder;


void async task Create_MyFolder(){

    Folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(MyFolder, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
}
```

I think it's good way to program in this case use this CreationCollisionOption:

```
 CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists
```

Because you enter in your application, always delete this folder and data inside, and i think it's not a good idea... But explore the other "CreationCollisionOption", because u can interested for other option. Personally I prefer declare public folder and folder name because sure you will use in the future and it's not necessary to repeat this code all time...

Good luck, sorry for my english and tell us if you can solve your problem or if you need more information! :)

Comment: Sorry for providing less information in my question. I can able to create folder/directory in Isolated storage or storage folder, My requirement is to create folder in SD Card to save all my application data in device. 

Is it Possible?
And thank you for responding .... :)

Answer (score 1):

here it is sample code to do that

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
```

and than to create folder

```
StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync
("myFolder", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

see complete example [here](http://tizianocacioppolini.blogspot.in/2014/01/windows-phone-8-folders-and-files.html#.VFx0mfmUdys)